# no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I've this code:

```
    class XMLNode
    {
        //...
        template <typename T>
        bool getValue(T& t, const std::string& path) const
        {
            if (empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Empty node");
            }
            return nsXML::getValue(t, path, *node);
        }

        template <typename T>
        T getValue(const std::string& path) const
        {
            if (empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Empty node");
            }
            return nsXML::getValue<T>(path, *node);
        }
        //...
    };

class XMLData
{
    //...
    template <typename T>
    T getValue(const std::string& path)
    {
        return XMLNode(&mDocNode, 0).getValue(path); // ERROR LINE
    }
    //...
};
```

And gives me error

```
no matching function for call to ‘nsXML::XMLNode::getValue(const string&)’
note: candidates are:
note: template<class T> bool nsXML::XMLNode::getValue(T&, const string&) const
note: template<class T> T nsXML::XMLNode::getValue(const string&) const
```

Why does `g++` give me this error?

Comment: You need to pass some template parameter to that member function call: `XMLNode(&mDocNode, 0).getValue<SomeType>(path);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler has no way to assess with which type you want to instantiate the function template. In this case you have to specify it explicitly:

```
return XMLNode(&mDocNode, 0).getValue<T>(path);
                                   // ^-- explicit instantiation
```

Only in some cases the template argument can be deduced by the compiler automatically from the function arguments:

```
int i;
bool b = XMLNode(&mDocNode, 0).getValue(i, path);
```

Here, the compiler sees an int as the first function argument and can deduce T for this function call to be int, so its the same as

```
bool b = XMLNode(&mDocNode, 0).getValue<int>(i, path);
```

Answer (score 0):

because your XMLNode::getValue(const std::string& path) function is a const, so when it's calling nsXML::getValue, it's looking for the const version, I guess there isn't a const one defined.

Note a const member function and a non const member function are different.